# Summary of a share percentage calculation from two tables

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

I want to return the result of summary of a share percentage calculation from two tables but I have no idea on how to do this. My table is as follows:

table **pa**

```
---+-----------+---------+-----------+---------+-----------+---------+----------+
id | product_1 | share_1 | product_2 | share_2 | product_3 | share_3 |  amount  |
---+-----------+---------+-----------+---------+-----------+---------+----------+
 1 |    3      |   50    |     2     |    50   |           |         |  5000    |
 2 |    2      |   50    |     1     |    25   |     4     |   25    |  10000   |
 3 |    5      |   50    |     4     |    50   |           |         |  7000    |
---+-----------+---------+-----------+---------+-----------+---------+----------+
```

table **products**

```
---+-----------+
id | name      |
---+-----------+
 1 | Book      |
 2 | Pen       |
 3 | Ruler     |
 4 | Pencil    |
 5 | Calendar  |
---+-----------+
```

I want the result to came out like this:

```
Product_name | Total
-------------+----------
Book         | 2500
Pen          | 7500
Ruler        | 2500
Pencil       | 6000
Calendar     | 3500
-------------+----------
Grand Total  | 22000
```

As far, I've tried this query

```
$this->db->select('t1.name as product_name, sum(t2.amount) as total');
$this->db->from('products t1');
$this->db->join('pa t2', 't2.product_1 = t1.id OR t2.product_2 = t1.id OR t2.product_3 = t1.id', 'left');
$this->db->group_by('t1.name');
$query = $this->db->get();
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/471c4/1

But it not returning the result I want since there's no calculation for the share percentage for each product.

Is there any way to return the result I want with only SQL query? Or do I have to do the calculation recursively with PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the calculation by first unpivoting the data:

```
select p.name, sum(amount)
from ((select product_1 as pid, amount*share_1 / 100.0 as amount from pa) union all
      (select product_2 as pid, amount*share_2 / 100.0 as amount from pa) union all
      (select product_3 as pid, amount*share_3 / 100.0 as amount from pa)
     ) pp join
     product p
     on pp.pid = p.id
group by p.name
```

You can get the total either in the application or by using `ROLLUP`.

Comment: You sir are awesome. I just adding right join to show other products that not in the pa table (I actually have 15 items in the products table)

Answer (score 0):

Try below SQL:

```
SELECT product_name, SUM(percentage)
FROM
(
    SELECT  t1.name as product_name, t2.share_1, t2.amount, (t2.share_1*t2.amount)/100 as percentage        
    FROM products t1 JOIN pa t2 ON  t2.product_1 = t1.id
    GROUP BY t1.name
    UNION
    SELECT  t1.name as product_name, t2.share_2, t2.amount, (t2.share_2*t2.amount)/100         as percentage        
    FROM products t1 JOIN pa t2 ON  t2.product_2 = t1.id
    GROUP BY t1.name
    UNION
    SELECT  t1.name as product_name, t2.share_3, t2.amount, (t2.share_3*t2.amount)/100 as percentage        
    FROM products t1 JOIN pa t2 ON  t2.product_3 = t1.id
    GROUP BY t1.name
) as temp_table
GROUP BY product_name
```

[**SqlFiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/471c4/17)